# Get all edges linked to a given node in a networkx graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

Just wondering if there is convenient `networkx` function that returns a list of edges connected to a given node (or nodes) (e.g. `my_node_name`) in a graph (e.g. `G`).

I can do it this way:

```
edlist=[]
for ed in G.edges():
    if 'my_node_name' in ed:
        edlist.append(ed)
```

but expect there might be a better way?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If the graph is undirected, you can use

```
G.edges(node)
```

In **networkx 2.x** this is an `EdgeDataView` object.  In **networkx 1.x** this is a list - if you want a generator in 1.x  rather than getting the whole list, `G.edges_iter(node)` works (this no longer exists in 2.x).

If the graph is directed the command above will not give the in-edges.  Use

```
G.in_edges(node)
G.out_edges(node)
```

These are views in 2.x.  In 1.x these are lists and there are generator options: `G.in_edges_iter(node)` and `G.out_edges_iter(node)`

Answer (score 18):

You can use the method `edges` on a node for an *un-directed* graph:

```
G.edges(['my_node_name'])
```

or the function [`edges`](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.edges.html#networkx.classes.function.edges)

```
networkx.edges(G, ['my_node_name'])
```

But for *directed* graphs the above method will only give the out-edges; there you need to call and combine both [`in_edges()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_edges.html) and [`out_edges()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_edges.html).

Comment: Warning - if the graph is directed, this will only give the out-edges.

Answer (score 1):

For directed multi-graphs, I found the following workaround for out-edges:

```
import networkx as nx

a = nx.MultiDiGraph()
a.add_edge("a", "b", 0)
a.add_edge("a", "b", 1)
a.add_edge("b", "c", 0)
a.add_edge("b", "c", 1)

# This is too much:
print(a.edges)
# OutMultiEdgeView([('a', 'b', 0), ('a', 'b', 1), ('b', 'c', 0), ('b', 'c', 1)])

# This is insufficient:
print(a.in_edges("b"))
# InMultiEdgeDataView([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b')])

# This is just right
print(a["a"])
# AdjacencyView({'b': {0: {}, 1: {}}})
print(a["a"]["b"])
# AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {}})
```

For in-edges, you should probably first use `a.in_edges(node)` and then `a[source][node]` to get the edge types.

Once you get all the triplets `t = (source, sink, type)`, you can access the edge by calling `a.edges[t]`.