# get corresponding edges and weight for the nodes in a network

Tags: python, networking, nodes, edges

I have the following network with nodes : "a", "b", "c" ,and these nodes have different edges with different weights("count"). How would I create a function where it takes a node and give me corresponding color(edge) with the max weight?

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
nodes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
edges = [('a', 'red', {'count': 4}),
      ('a', 'blue', {'count': 12}),
      ('a', 'orange', {'count': 33}),
      ('b', 'purple', {'count': 4}),
      ('b', 'red', {'count': 11}),
      ('c', 'red', {'count': 9}),
      ('c', 'orange', {'count': 6}),
      ('c', 'yellow', {'count': 7})]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Comment: networkx has built in functions to retrieve edges from a node after built.  This is a good start:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078907/get-all-edges-linked-to-a-given-node-in-a-networkx-graph

Comment: I'm sorry, how is this a graph?? How are the edges connected?

Comment: I made the edges up, you can think of abc and the colours as locations and the count as the distance between...it may not look like a graph....but I am only looking for concepts here.

Comment: thanks Jeff for the link :). I have something but it's giving me nothing. could you please take a look at my codes and maybe provide some advice? ```                  
`def get_max(graph,node):
    edge_names=[]
    for ed in G.edges:
        for i in nodes:
            if i in ed:
                edge_names.append(ed)
            return`