# Get all edges linked to given node with data in networkx graph

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx, graph-theory

I have a networkx graph `g` that has edges with weights, and I want to get all the edges along with their weights that are linked to a given node, say node `1`. I know that I can do something like `g.edges(1)`, however this will only get the edges, but not actually their associated weight attributes.

In effect, I want to do something like `g.edges().data()` by only for edges linked to a give node, something like `g.edges(1).data()`, but that doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this, or do I have to do a manual search over all edges?

Comment: does this link answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/33252014/5817977

Comment: @skibee no it doesn't. read the question carefully (and his/her comment in the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Graph.adj`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.adj.html#networkx.Graph.adj) to do that.

try the following example:

```
g.adj[1] # should return information including the weights
```

---

**update:**

To get the data when running [`.edges()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html#networkx.Graph.edges), you can just pass the `data` as a key-word argument instead.

```
FG.edges(1, data="weight")
```

Comment: Thank you! That only gives me the adjacent nodes and so I would still need to do some processing to turn them into the correct format for edges. Right now, I am doing this: `[(e[0], e[1], g.get_edge_data(*e)['weight']) for e in g.edges(1)]`, any more elegant suggestion?